# Repeat script for multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hey i have this code:

```
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<td class="first">100</td>
</tr>
</table>
<h4 class=curs style="display:none">10</h4>
    <script>
    document.body.onload = function(){
         var firstTdVal = document.getElementsByClassName('first')[0].innerHTML;
       var secondTdVal = document.getElementsByClassName('curs')[0].innerHTML;
       var valueToBeShown = parseInt(firstTdVal)/ parseInt(secondTdVal);
       document.getElementsByClassName('first')[0].innerHTML = valueToBeShown ;
    }
    </script>
</body>
```

As you see ".first" has a number in it,this number is divied to ".curs" and the result is showed in ".first" too.Now the problem is that for exemple i add 100 more td's with class ".second,.third...,.hundred" in table.How to make script to do the same for all td's as it does for the ".first"(devide to ".curs").How do i do this in my JS by keeping it complex.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nr2pLyuz/5/

Comment: is there only one tag with class="curs" for divide operation or more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `document.querySelectorAll` to get an array of matched elements (matched with CSS selector), then loop through them using `forEach`, applying you logic one `td` at a time. Like this:

```
// querySelector gets the first element matched. textContent get the text of that element
var cursValue = parseInt(document.querySelector(".curs").textContent);

// querySelectorAll get an array of all the matched elements
var tds = document.querySelectorAll("td");
// loop through that array one td at a time
tds.forEach(function(td){
    // get the text of the current td
    var value = parseInt(td.textContent);

    // if the value is not valid (a string for example) return and don't process anymore for this td (go straight to the next one).
    if(isNaN(value)) return;

    // calculate the new value
    value = value / cursValue;
    // change the text of this td (update it to the new value)
    td.textContent = value;
});
```

**NOTE:** `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` match elements using [CSS selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp), so to match an element using a class the selector should be `".className"`, to match it using an ID: `"#someID"`, ... All CSS selectors are accepted (even this one: `"#anID>li.some-class a:not([href])"`).

**NOTE2:** `tds` is an array, so if you don't want to use `forEach` you can use a normal `for` loop (`for(var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) ...`).

Comment: Yeah the loop is that i needed thanks a lot ;).But there is a little problem,for exemple i have others td's in my table with 'names'-not numbers.Now after loop all names changed to NaN.How to solve this?

Comment: @RTX check the new edit. I've skipped the tds that do not contain valid numbers.

Answer (score 1):

This will iterate over your table (be sure to set the table ID) (open dev console to view output but it's pretty straight forward.)

```
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
for (var row of table.rows) {
    for (var col of row.cells) {
        console.log(col.className, col.innerHTML); //Class names and the values of the elements.
    }  
}
```

If you need anymore help please ask because I do not fully understand what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Now imagine that i have 100 td's ,all with different classes,and all have to be devided to ".curs".Need to do it simple with js

Comment: I cant create js code with 200 lines :),too long,and slow

Comment: I need just when i add new td with class ".third" or else td with another class,to devide it to ".curs" and show it in the same td.

Comment: Yeah,on jsfiddle it works well,but on my site it doesnt,hmm

Comment: Did you set the table ID?

Comment: Not sure will have to see more code to understand why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way where you put the number to be divided by in the first `td`, the number to divide by in the second `td`, and the result will be placed in the third `td`.

```js
var trs = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
for (var i = 0; i< trs.length; i++) {
  var tds = trs[i].getElementsByTagName('td'),
      first = tds[0].textContent,
      second = tds[1].textContent,
      third = tds[2],
      result = (parseInt(first) / parseInt(second));
  third.innerHTML = result;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```